# One-sided variance test in r

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, variance

I would like to compare variances of two independent samples (of different sizes) from two unknown distributions. It seems I should use a one-sided nonparametric test. 
Bartlett's and Fligner's tests are two-sided, am I right?
What test in R could I use to determine which sample has greater variance?

For example, consider two samples:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100,200,56)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need a one-sided test?  What exactly is your hypothesis?

Comment: With only two samples your Bartlett should be equivalent to the ratio of variances test and the Levene to a t-test on the absolute deviations from the mean; in both cases they can be done one-tailed